# How to provide VS Code with a self signed certificate in order to connect with SAP-System via Fiori exntenxion tool

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssl-certificate, sap-fiori

I have been learning SAP Fiori lately and have been so far using the open service of Northwind.

Now I want to try to get the data from my own SAP-System. The SAP Fiori exntension Tool for VS Code allows you to add SAP-Systems (as seen below).
[add SAP-System to Visual-studio-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTjGh.png)
I have filled all the necessary information (including Client, Username and Password) but I'm getting this error message.

I have found many guides which either did not give me what I needed or they did and I was just unable to understand it. I have tried a couple of things, played a around in the transaction `STRUST` and downloaded some certificates (that I personally find dubious) onto my local PC. I believe I have to add my local Host to `STRUST` somehow but I have no idea how (or whether the approach is even right) I have never done anything of this sort so any tip would be appreciated.

Extra Info:
I'm connected to the SAP-System via VPN and typing the IP-Address + Port in my browser actually "works" after pressing my way through the warnings I get to a page with a big "404 Error" message  in the middle and the SAP logo on the bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps, which helped me to resolve similar issue:

1. Access with browser any OData service metadata document URL on your SAP system and download Root CA certificate. Root certificate is usually the first one in the hierarchy of 3 certificates available there. Certificate file will be downloaded with ".crt" extension by default.
2. Right-click the CA certificate file and select Install Certificate.
3. Add Windows Environment variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS with path to this ".crt" file as well.
4. Restart Visual Studio Code and try again.